How to change columns values(list) using another data frame in Python
I have two data frame, I need to change column values of first data frame that are in list, using second data frame.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'title':['The Godfather','Fight Club','The Empire'], 'genre_ids':[[18, 80],[18],[12, 28, 878]]})

    title           genre_ids
0   The Godfather   [18, 80]
1   Fight Club      [18]
2   The Empire      [12, 28, 878]


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[18,80,12,28,878,99],'name':['Action','Adventure','Adventure','Animation','Comedy','Documentary']})


    id  name
0   18  Action
1   80  Horror
2   12  Adventure
3   28  Animation
4   878 Comedy
5   99  Documentary

How can I assign genere_ids like this using df2 in python
       title       genre_ids  
0   The Godfather  [Action, Horror] 
1   Fight Club     [Action]
2   The Empire     [Adventure, Animation, Comedy]


You can also first map the genre IDs in df1 to their corresponding names using df2, and then replacing the genre IDs with the mapped names, like the following:
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'title':['The Godfather','Fight Club','The Empire'], 'genre_ids':[[18, 80],[18],[12, 28, 878]]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[18,80,12,28,878,99],'name':['Action','Adventure','Adventure','Animation','Comedy','Documentary']})

genre_map = dict(zip(df2['id'], df2['name']))

df1['genre_ids'] = df1['genre_ids'].apply(lambda x: [genre_map[id] for id in x])

print(df1)

Output:
          title                   genre_ids
0  The Godfather            [Action, Adventure]
1     Fight Club                    [Action]
2     The Empire  [Adventure, Animation, Comedy]


You can do (note: id 80 is Adventure in your example, not Horror):
m = dict(zip(df2["id"], df2["name"]))
df1["genre_ids"] = df1["genre_ids"].apply(lambda l: [m.get(v) for v in l])

print(df1)

Prints:
           title                       genre_ids
0  The Godfather             [Action, Adventure]
1     Fight Club                        [Action]
2     The Empire  [Adventure, Animation, Comedy]


You can explode the genre_ids and merge the 2 dataframe.
merged = df1.explode('genre_ids').merge(df2,left_on='genre_ids',right_on='id')[['title','name']]

Then using groupby convert the name column to the list.
result = merged.groupby('title')['name'].apply(list).reset_index()

The result will be :
           title                            name
0     Fight Club                        [Action]
1     The Empire  [Adventure, Animation, Comedy]
2  The Godfather             [Action, Adventure]

